# How do i create textbox dynamically and insert value into database on C# windows form application

Tags: c#, winforms, sqlite

I am currently working on a C# windows form project that would be used to calculate personal income tax for employee, i am having issue with my client weird requirement of creating allowances dynamically on the form, companies have different policies concerning which allowance would be given to thier employee, i have tried to captured the popular allowances in the application, and also provided a textbox for other allowances, so could enter the sum value of other allowances that is not included in the application form since the application is not going to be used for only one company, the issue now is: my client does not want the others allowances texbox that i included on the form, he wants to be able to click on somthing on the form and that should open where he can type in any other allowances that was not included on the form fields, i have tried the approach of putting a label for allowance name and allowance amount on the form, but this didn't seem to work since enteries could only be done once for each employee very month and thier allowances could up to ten sometimes depending on the company. I dont know whether any of our senior colleadgues here had done anything similar to this, i will appreciate if they could share thier knowledge with me. Thanks

Comment: Why don't you use a grid control for allowances?

Comment: if i use gird control that will allow users to enter multiple allowances for a particular employee at once, how will i save them to database and display same in different columns in the report? seeing i will be saving into only two fields (Allowance name, and Allowance Amount)

Comment: "how will I save them to database" - in a table Allowances.

Comment: Please what would be the fields of the table? seeing that the number of fields for other allowances are not known at the point of programme development, sometimes it could be 10, sometimes 5, sometimes 2 etc, are you going to be creating the fields on the fly, if you do this, that means the table is going to have too many fields at the end of the day, because the application is going to be used for more than one client

Comment: An `Allowances` table like this perhaps: | id(PK)| employeeID(FK) | taxFormId(FK) | allowanceDesc | allowanceAmount | seqNumber |